# HTML image tag – properties width/height and srcset

Tags: html

I am wondering, since I cannot find anything about that topic, what's the deal with the properties `width` and `height` of an image tag when it comes to using `srcset`?

I am aware that `width` and `height` is used for browsers to allocate the proper dimensions of the image so that the page does not jump once the asset was fetched. But are these two properties still needed or maybe even harmful when used together with `srcset`?

All the documentation I found regarding `srcset` omit `width` and `height` altogether, but never with any explanation...

Comment: [`sizes`](https://css-tricks.com/sometimes-sizes-is-quite-important/).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am aware of `sizes` but it does not answer my question: Does using `width` and `height` together with `srcset` serve any purpose and will it even be potentially harmful?

Comment: You're right; it's not an answer, it's a comment. You did not mention `sizes` in your question, so I didn't know if you were aware of them. I would suggest that `sizes` takes the place of `width` and `height` when using `srcset`. Trying to find out what the specs say...

Comment: The attributes width and height still provide the ratio to the browser and should be provided with the default src attribute